# Gatling - passing data from feeder to method in exec

Tags: java, scala, csv, gatling

Im new to Gatling and I'm trying to reuse test scripts I'm using for functional testing I wrote in RestAssured/Java to work with gatling. So what I do to call my login methods is I call them in `wrapperForJavaMethods` method(line 4) before calling the last method in "gatling fashion"(line 6 ). If I just put strings as arguments in line 4 it works perfectly well but when I'm trying to use feeder's variable `${login}` is printed, for comparison in line 7(where it makes no logical sense to call feeder's variable I just did it for debugging purposes) data from csv is printed. Is there anyway in which I can pass data from csv feeder to method's parameters or can they only be. called in session?

```
  val csvCredentails = csv("data/data.csv")//1
  val scenario = scenario("my custom scenario")//1
    .feed(csvCredentails)//3
    .exec(wrapperForJavaMethods("${login}","${pass}"))//4
    .exec(http("login")//5
      .post("/login")//6
      .check(status is "${login}")//7

  def wrapperForJavaMethods(login: String, pass: String): Unit = {
    print("login11 " + username + " pass " + password)
    objectOfJavaClass.inputCredentials(username, password)
    objecyOfJavaClass.anotherJavaMethod
    objecyOfJavaClass.anotherJavaMethod2
    objecyOfJavaClass.anotherJavaMethod3
...

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: Gatling founder here

First, I'm very skeptical about what you're trying to build.

- RestAssured and other functional test tools are not implemented for heavy load. Typically, they are not built on top of a fast non-blocking HTTP client. It's not just their target use case.
  Triggering RestAssured from a Gatling's orchestrator won't make it able to generate large loads like genuine Gatling HTTP module does.
  Moreover, such blocking APIs don't play nice when plugged into an async engine like Gatling's.
- Are you really sure your connections usage will match what happens on your target's system? RestAssured will either use a shared connection pool, or no connection pool at all. I suspect you won't be able to implement a connection pool per virtual user. Again, functional test tools are not designed for this.

Then, regarding the code you shared, this is not how [Gatling Expression Language](https://gatling.io/docs/current/session/expression_el/) works. You would have to resolve your parameters in a function. Please check the [Session API](https://gatling.io/docs/current/session/session_api/).